# Does an API Gateway REST API with cross-account Lambda proxy integration network traffic goes via internet?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

We have a use case to invoke a lambda function in one account being called from AWS API Gateway in another account and both the accounts are of same organization. How is the network traffic directed? Will the traffic go through internet or will it use VPC network internally?

Tried to find the documentation around it but no clue.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.